# Update SSL certificate on chef-clients

Tags: chef-infra

A remote node running chef to checkin to the chef-server requires the certificate file to be in `/etc/chef/trusted_certs/`.  I initially handle this through a script that I wrote during my node provisioning process.

However, for deployed hosts, I can't do that anymore.  I just had to update my SSL certificate for my chef-server, so now I need to update the remote nodes.

So what's the best way to update the needed SSL certificates on deployed chef-clients that I don't have direct access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to update it using Chef itself, though this would mean you need to be careful to fully roll out the new public/CA certificate before to all hosts before updating the private half on the Chef server. In general this shouldn't come up much. If you expect to be regenerating the server's key a lot, you should probably use a more formal internal CA and just deploy the CA cert (which rarely changes) to the hosts.

The specifics of the update would probably be a cookbook_file resource and cram all the certs to trust in a cookbook somewhere.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but wasn't sure if it was 'safe'.  So, considering my .crt filename hasn't changed (still dev.myserver.crt), but the contents have what is a good way to ensure I don't 'brick' a host from being able to contact the server in the future since I would have to overwrite the trusted_certs/dev.myserver.crt file?

Comment: The filename is irrelevant (other than the ending), you'll need to have both there during the migration. Make it `dev.myserver.crt` and `dev2.myserver.crt` if you have to.